# google maps in jquery ui dialog doesn't full load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui

I have a problem in my website with the google maps api javascript 
is working on other pages but not in other pages .

image of error 
[image]

my code

```js
var map = "";

function loadMap2(link) {
  var currentMapPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(link.attr('data-lati'), link.attr('data-longt'));
  var mapOptions = {
    center: currentMapPosition,
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  if (!map) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_cust"), mapOptions);
  } else {
    map.setOptions(mapOptions);
  }
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: currentMapPosition,
    map: map,
    title: 'SubProject Location'
  });


  $("#map_cust").dialog({
    title: "خريطة العميل : " + link.attr('data-name'),
    height: 400,
    width: "80%"
  });
}

$(document).on('click', '.show_map2', function() {
  loadMap2($(this));
  return false;
})
```

and i have a second question how to delete the marker if i show map second time .
and thanks for all .

Comment: may we know the difference between the pages?

Comment: all css file and also javascript .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all i solved it with add the display:none; to div #

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I ended up writting a refresh method. is in coffescript but you can get the idea in js

```
refresh:->
    center=@map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(@map, 'resize')
    @map.setCenter(center)
```

Hope it helps

https://github.com/Sudakatux/GMapWrapper/blob/master/MapWrapper.coffee

This is what really does the trick (javascript compiled)

```
 MapWrapper.prototype.refresh = function() {
      return google.maps.event.trigger(this.map, 'resize');
    };
```

Hope it helps